# Warning Object at URL '...' for property 'og:image:url' could not be parsed as type 'url'

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

i use the following meta

```
   <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.3" />
        <meta property="og:title" content="Retour vers le pr&eacute;sent">
        <meta property="og:type" content="website">
        <meta property="og:url" content="http://retourverslepresent.be/">
        <meta property="og:image" content="http:/retourverslepresent.be/img/newfb.jpg">
        <meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpg">
        <meta property="og:image:width" content="1200">
        <meta property="og:image:height" content="630">
        <meta property="og:description" content="Venez (re)découvrir la trilogie ce 21 octobre 2015">
```

but when i try to debug the page with

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/

i got the error :

Object at URL 'http://retourverslepresent.be/' of type 'website' is invalid because the given value 'http:/retourverslepresent.be/img/newfb.jpg' for property 'og:image:url' could not be parsed as type 'url'.

Any idea why ?

Answer (score 0):

it was missing a / to my url so i replace
property="og:image" content="**http:/**retourverslepresent.be/.. 
by
meta property="og:image" content="**http://**retourverslepresent.be/..